# Getting all item from dictionary inside dictionary by list comprehension in python for multiple days

Tags: python, dictionary, flask, list-comprehension

I am trying to make a simple weather app and I am trying to get all icons by list comprehension. I can't find a way to do that and I can't find any solution so if someone know please let me know.
here is data that I am getting from web API. I am capable to do it by days for single one but I can't find a way for list comprehensions
thanks

my current code:

```
   data = {
            'icon': response['data'][0]['weather']['icon'],
            'icon2': response['data'][1]['weather']['icon'],
            'icon3': response['data'][2]['weather']['icon'],
            'icon4': response['data'][3]['weather']['icon'],
         }
```

and i would like to get something like this

```
 data = {
         icons = #list comprehension
        }
```

api result

```
 {'data': [{'app_max_temp': 12.2, 'weather':  {'icon': 'c01d', 'code': 800, 'description': 'Clear 
 Sky'}'min_temp': 5, 
{ 'app_max_temp': 13.7, 'weather': {'icon':'c01d','code': 800, 'description': 'Clear Sky'}, 
'min_temp': 5,
{'app_max_temp': 12.1, 'weather': {'icon': 'c02d', 'code': 802, 'description': 'Scattered 
clouds'}'min_temp': 8, 
{ 'app_max_temp':  11.8,  'weather': {'icon': 'r01d', 'code': 500, 'description': 
'Light rain'}, 'min_temp': 6,}
```

Comment: Do you mean `icons = [x['weather']['icon'] for x in response['data']]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this:

```
icons = [row['weather']['icon'] for row in api_result['data']]
```

Answer (score 0):

If your api result is corrected to:

```
api_result = {'data': 
        [{'app_max_temp': 12.2, 
          'weather':  {'icon': 'c01d', 'code': 800, 'description': 'Clear Sky'},
          'min_temp': 5}, 
         { 'app_max_temp': 13.7, 
          'weather': {'icon':'c01d','code': 800, 'description': 'Clear Sky'}, 
          'min_temp': 5},
        {'app_max_temp': 12.1, 
         'weather': {'icon': 'c02d', 'code': 802, 'description': 'Scattered clouds'},
         'min_temp': 8}, 
        { 'app_max_temp':  11.8,  
         'weather': {'icon': 'r01d', 'code': 500, 'description': 'Light rain'}, 
         'min_temp': 6,}
        ]}
```

then using the enumerate function to assist with naming your keys, you can do something like the following.

```
data = {f'icon{icon_index}': icon['weather']['icon'] 
        for icon_index, icon in enumerate(api_result['data'], start=1)}
```

It outputs:

```
{'icon1': 'c01d', 'icon2': 'c01d', 'icon3': 'c02d', 'icon4': 'r01d'}
```